# Complete measure spaces and convergence in $L^p(\mu)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Problem: Let $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a complete measure space. Prove that, if $f_n(x)$ converges to $f(x)$ in $L^3(\mu)$, then $f^3_n(x)$ converges to $f^3(x)$ in $L^1(\mu)$.

My attempt: Let $\|f\|_p = \left(\int_X|f|^p\,d\mu\right)^{1/p}$. Then $$f \in L^3(\mu) \implies \|f\|_3 < \infty \implies \|f^3\|_1 = \|f\|^3_3 < \infty  \implies f^3 \in L^1(\mu).$$

My issue: I don't feel like this proof is complete or correct; I didn't use the fact that $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ is a complete measure space (at least, not explicitly; if I implicitly assumed it, I'm unsure where), and I'm not confident that my first and last implications are correct (I'm used to seeing things like $L^3[0, 1]$, but not $L^3(\mu)$).

My request: If anyone could guide my apparent misunderstandings of the concepts used here, I would greatly appreciate it. If I'm on the wrong track, I'd also appreciate a nudge in the right direction (but NOT a full solution).

Extra info: I'm using Royden's *Real Analysis*

Comment: So far all you have shown is that $f^3$ (and similarly $f_n^3$) is in $L^1(\mu)$. You have yet to show that $f_n^3$ converges to $f^3$ in $L^1(\mu)$.

Comment: So does that mean I need to show $\|f_n^3 - f^3\|_1 \rightarrow 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suchan mentioned in the comment section, you need to show that $\|f_n^3 - f^3\|_{L^1} \to 0$.

Hint1: $$|f_n^3 - f^3| = |f_n - f||f_n^2 + f^2 +f_nf|.$$

Hint2:

> Use Holder's inequality with $p = 3$ and $q = \frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: Ok, I think I might have most of it now: $$\|f_n^3 - f^3\|_1 = \|(f_n - f)(f_n^2 + f_nf + f^2)\|_1$$ $$\leq \|f_n - f\|_3\|f_n^2 + f_nf + f^2\|_{3/2}$$ $$\leq \|f_n - f\|_3(\|f_n^2\|_{3/2} + \|f_nf\|_{3/2} + \|f^2\|_{3/2}) = \|f_n - f\|_3(\|f_n\|^2_3 + \|f_nf\|_{3/2} + \|f\|^2_3)$$. The terms $\|f_n\|^2_3$ and $\|f\|^2_3$ are both finite, so the only thing I have left to show is that $\|f_nf\|_{3/2}$ is finite...

Comment: Ah! But via Holder again, $$\|f_nf\|_{3/2} \leq \|f_n^{3/2}\|^{2/3}_2\|f^{3/2}\|^{2/3}_2 = \|f_n\|_3\|f\|_3$$ which is finite. Then I can use an $\epsilon$ argument to show convergence

Comment: @d4rk_1nf1n1ty: You are almost there! Then the only thing you need now is to show that $\|f_n\|_{L^3}$ is uniformly bounded and then you are done!

Comment: Would it be enough to say that, since $f_n, f \in L^3(\mu)$, their $L^3(\mu)$-norms are bounded?

Comment: @d4rk_1nf1n1ty: unfortunately it is not enough. Indeed, for what we know so far $\|f_n\|_3$ could be as big as $n$, so that passing to the limit is not possible right away. You really need to prove an inequality of the form $\|f_n\|_3 \le K$, for some fixed $K$ independent of $n$.

Comment: Here's my thought: $$||f_n||_3 = ||f_n - f + f||_3 \leq ||f_n - f||_3 + ||f||_3$$ so if $||f||_3 = M_1$ and, if we choose large enough $n$, $||f_n - f||_3 \leq M_2$, we can let $K = M_1 + M_2$.

Comment: @d4rk_1nf1n1ty: looks great, good job!

Comment: Last thing, could you comment briefly on where "$(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ is a complete measure space" is used? I'm not understanding why that was an important assumption to make.

Comment: @d4rk_1nf1n1ty: I honestly don't see where that assumption is being used. Indeed we are essentially only applying Holder's inequality a bunch of times. Moreover, it is not even a strong assumption as any measure space can be completed.